# Json data parse into table in java transformation in informatica developer

Tags: java, json, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have data in below format-

```
{
"result": [
    {
        "number": "C12",
        "name": "ABC"
    },
    {
        "number": "D12",
        "name": "BCD"
       
    },
    {
        "number": "E56",
        "name": "fm"
     }]
}
```

My code is -

```
String result = //that store my above json data;
try{
    String jsonString = result;
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(jsonString);
    JSONArray arr = obj.getJSONArray("result");
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++)
     {
        String num = arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("number");
        String name= arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("name");
        generateRow();
     }
   }
 catch(Exception e)
  {
        e.printStackTrace(); 
  }
```

But with this code i am able to read only first record.

Please help in writing the code where i can read all the records.

Comment: use your script in a java code(create a new .java file) and see if its working? infa JTX isnt any different that java code.

Comment: @KoushikRoy it is working but only returning one row.

Comment: @BuildSlayer could you please add your output here.

Comment: Now working for me also. My java transformation was not checked as active

Answer (score 0):

You can move to Informatica developer tool in case you have the license and use H2R transformation